# Python Setuptools installation error: Could not create ssl/tls secure channel

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to install Python Setuptools in Windows 10 following instructions on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/3.5.1.

I tried this in two ways:

- by running ez_setup.py in Windows Command Prompt
- by running `(Invoke-WebRequest https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py).Content | python` in Windows Powershell

Both ways I get the same error message: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Why is Windows not able to download the Setuptool installation file? What do I need to do enable Windows to create a secure SSL/TLS secure channel?

Comment: This is no longer an issue to me because I checked I with pip list that Python Setuptools is already installed. As far as I can tell, it was installed when I installed Python.